# Are VBA programs runnable on different Access versions?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I don't know much about Access but I have a few programs that have the .mdb extension that I'm trying to get working on a computer with Access 2016 or office 365 Access.  They are currently running on a computer with Access 2003.  Is some conversion to the program needed to run on the newer Access?

I believe they are VBA file and have the .mdb extension but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: They may run with little or no issues. Why don't you try? As the programs are yours, you should be able to solve the bumps you may encounter.

Comment: @Gustav they are not written by me and I don't know vb or Access I just use them

Comment: I would 1. try to open it, 2. convert it to .accdb (File -> Save as).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you first want to check if  you using Access/Office x64 bits, or Access/Office x32 bits.

Office now comes in 2 flavors. The lengthy history of Office was delivered as a x32 bit product.

However, since a few years ago (about 2-3), Office started defaulting as a x64 bit version.

While there is NOT a specific file format for x32 vs x64 bit versions of Access, some VBA code "might" need some love and care to run correctly as x64 bits.

So, while the data files and using such data should not a be a issue, VBA code can "often" require some changes. (in most cases, you don't require any changes to VBA).

The next issue is that Access is quite special in the Office suite, as it is a developers tool. That means you can create applications, and that is a WHOLE NEW ball game!

So, having JUST stated that mdb or newer accDB files in regards to data (tables) don't care about x32 vs x64 bit versions.

If you have ANY mde, or accDE files: they are compiled files for the code. As a result, you can NOT run a mde or accDE created with access x32 in access x64.

(You need the source code mdb, or accDB files, and have to re-compile those using Access x64 bits).

And keep in mind the mdb files are 25 years old! Now, I would bet that you NOT using any other software programs that are 25 years old.

So, Access 2003 - again, that is over 20 years old! Are you maintaining any other developers code from 20 years ago? Again you need to keep that in mind.

The mdb files SHOULD be able to be opened by Access 2019 or very latest version.

However, there are 2-3 significant issues.

As noted, "mde" or so called compiled Access applications, they require you to have the original source code project, and have to be re-compiled to work with Office x64.

And the other issue: WorkGroup security.

In those days (20 years ago), often a company did not have a server based system, did not have Windows logons etc. So, for small business, you STILL often wanted a application that could be secured with user logons. So, up to access 2007, and 2010: they supported what is called Access workgroup security.

However, it's either 2013, or 2016 (not sure), but they DO NOT support workgroup security any more. To be fair, this feature was not often used, but in many cases, way back then, more experienced developers did use this security feature of Access. You can easy see if that security option was used, since when you launch the application, you be prompted for a user + password.

However, given that those mdb files are 20+ years old, it is a VERY good idea to create a new blank accDB file, and import everything from the older mdb file into a fresh new accDB file. That way, you have another 20 years of use!

So the answer is "sort of yes", you can probably just open + use those mdb files. However, it also a VERY good idea to migrate those older files to newer formats if they are still valuable to your organization.

In fact, in most cases, you can just open the mdb file, and then Ctrl-G (jumps to the VBA development system, and then from the menu go debug->compile. If the  VBA code compiles, then you are in great shape.

However, as noted, it still a VERY good idea to migrate to newer formats, since it is unlikely that you using say a 20 year old accounting package, or say a 20+ year old version of SQL server. In other words, since everything else is not so old, then the same love and care over time should be given to those older access files.

So, just try opening them. If they have any VBA code, then try a compile, and if the code compiles, then you much good to go.

As noted, if the mdb file(s) have a lot of VBA code, then the greater chance that the VBA may not compile correctly. As noted, most x32 bit VBA access files should compile and run as x64 bits, but you have to try a compile.

So, as noted, we have 2 (or 3) challenges.

We now using by default x64 bit versions of Office. This will effect Access applications (or can).

And if you have any mde, or accDE files, then again that can be a issue, since they are pre-compiled Access applications without the source code. And those can NOT be converted from x32 access to x64 access without the original mdb/accDB files and the source code in those "applications".

Comment: Note that there may be a fourth challenge, mdb files may have been created in really old versions of Access that are no longer supported in Access 2013 and newer (Access  97 and older). This has been a real-life problem for me and had me somehow find a version of Access 2003 to do the conversion to modern mdb. I've encountered a workplace that ran Access 2003 until recently since they did not know how to do this conversion, and support was already limited in Access 2007.

Comment: Yes, there are mdb formats of 2000-2003, and then a format that pre-dates 2000 mdb, and those are ansi-coded mdb files (office 97, 95). They don't support nor have uni-code characters. And you are correct - I noted in my post that some mdb files that pre-date a2000 can't be opened anymore. I better hold on to my a2003 office disk a bit longer then, right!  - thanks for the follow up.

Comment: ( cc: @ErikA ) re: "I better hold on to my a2003 office disk a bit longer then, right!" - If you want to be able to convert a *really old* .mdb from Access 95 or Access 2.0 then you'd best hang on to a copy of Access 2000 as well. Access 2003 could open such files using a separate add-on from Microsoft but it is no longer available (ref: [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-access-2-0-and-access-95-databases-into-current-versions-2e9d8851-101d-4407-a881-65d06bb12aa7#bm3))